# Order of selected bones

Tags: python, rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to write a script that automates the creation of an IK Rig. But to do so I need to know in what order blender appends bones to this list, when I select them?  `bpy.context.selected_bones`  It doesn't seem to be the order I select them nor the alphabetic order from the bones names.

Comment: First, you want `selected_pose_bones` as `selected_bones` are the edit bones. The `active_pose_bone` is the one you put the constraint on. You could use `len(selected_pose_bones)` to set the chain length. You can walk along the bones using the `parent` or `child` properties.

Comment: thank you I didn't know about the `parent` and `child` thing.   But I do need the `selected_bones` since I am not only putting a constraint on a bone but I am also creating the bones before that with the script.
So the script takes `selected_bones` and adds a bone to the last bone in the list as the IK target. Then I put a constraint on the last bone of `selected_pose_bones`, add the new bone as target and set the chain length with the `len(selected_pose_bones)`. Same thing for the Pole Target, just diffrent positioning.
The problem remains: What is the order of these two lists?

Comment: To me it looks like `selected_pose_bones` is always from top most parent through to last child.

Comment: I think you're right `selected_pose_bones` is in order of the bone hierachie. The problem is `selected_bones` and `selected_editable_bones` are not. At least until I enter Pose Mode once. `selected_bones` is in order of bone creation until I enter Pose Mode and go back to Edit Mode, then they are in the 'correct' order. I don't really understand that concept but I think I can work arround it.
thank you for the help.